# Ostrio:files is not working properly after deploying the code on meteor galaxy

Tags: meteor

I am using ostrio:files for file storing. When I deploy my code on galaxy server, when user will fetch previous image data (previous data exists in database ), it also get URL from database of that image but when I hit on that URL, it shows ' File Not Found :frowning: ' .

Please advice, how I can solve the issue.

Server side---->

```
export const designImages = new FilesCollection({ collectionName: 'designImages' });
```

---------------> Client side---->

```
<img src={image.link()} alt="" className="img-responsive" />
```

Comment: Can you share some more code- like how are you referencing the url and `ostrio:files` settings

Comment: ---------------> Server side---->        

export const designImages = new FilesCollection({ collectionName: 'designImages' });


---------------> Client side---->     

<img src={image.link()} alt="" className="img-responsive" />

Comment: it should only be link not link()